# folder permission

Tags: c#

I need to change the access permissions of the folder in  c:\program data.

How can i change the permissions?

Thanks

Comment: User should have file system previliges can change the file or folder permission.

Comment: I suppose you don't want to write a program for that. Therefore this question is more suited for superuser.com than for stackoverflow.com. SuperUser is in private beta right now; you can find the password here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Comment: IMHO, this is a perfectly valid question for SO. It's 100% programming-related (what if you want to createa custom installer which needs to change permissions on some directory?)

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: If he wants to do it programmatically, yes. If he wants to do it by right-clicking, no. I assume the latter. That's why I gave the hint to ask on SU.

Comment: I assume he wants to do it programmatically, since he tagged the post with the C#-tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.SetAccessControl(directoryName, security)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol.aspx

Comment: He's asking about permissions on the folder, not the file.